# Deferring C++ static object construction - GCC on Linux

Tags: c++, gcc

Imagine I have a C++ class called `MyClass`.

Imagine that I have no access to the source code of `MyClass` ... it is contained in a library and I am supplied only the library and the header file for `MyClass`.

Imagine that the class itself requires environment pre-configuration ... for example ... before the constructor of the class can be called, I need to do some setup.   The class is normally meant to be used as follows:

```
void func() {
   doGlobalSetup();
   MyClass myInstance(1,2,3);
   myInstance.doSomething();
   ...
}
```

Now I have the situation where we need to create a global instance of the class such as:

```
MyClass myInstance(1,2,3);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   doGlobalSetup();
   myInstance.doSomething();
}
```

The problem is that in this story, the instance of `MyClass` is created **before** the call to `doGlobalSetup()`.  It is instantiated before `main()` is called.  What I want to do is either defer the creation of `myInstance()`  till later **or** be able to run `doGlobalSetup()` somehow before the instantiation of the class.

This is a simplification of the actual story ... so let us assume:

1. I can't change the internals of `MyClass`.
2. There must be an instance variable called `myInstance` of type `MyClass` (I can't change the logic to `MyClass *pMyInstance`).

Many thanks for reading.

Comment: Is `MyClass` copyable? Related, I would really consider whether you want to make a global instance ... However, if it's copyable then I think there is an easy solution.

Comment: Please stop using `void main`, ISO C++ permits `int main()` or `int main(int, char**)` only

Comment: @Danh - Sorry Danh ... it was meant to be pseudo code as opposed to a real app.  However I changed the text as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the GCC compiler environment there is a function attribute capability called `constructor`.  This allows us to flag a function definition with the ability for it to be automatically invoked **before** main is called and, most importantly **before** any class constructors are invoked.

Referring back to the original problem definition ... if the `doGlobalSetup()` function is modified from:

```
void doGlobalSetup() { ... }
```

to

```
__attribute__((constructor)) void doGlobalSetup() { ... }
```

then its invocation will occur before main is called and *also* before any static class instance constructors are called.  The explicit call to this function would also be removed from main() as its work has been performed implicitly.

Answer (score 5):

Since you've constrained the problem such that `new` cannot be used, you should be able to create the object as always and copy it to the global instance. For example:

```
MyClass createMyClass()
{
    doGlobalSetup();
    return MyClass(1, 2, 3);
}

MyClass myInstance = createMyClass();

int main()
{
    myInstance.doSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Arkadiy Yes, it does assume the `MyClass` is copyable and the question does not list a constraint stating otherwise. I also asked the OP about this but didn't get an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Does it suit your needs?

```
namespace
{
    int doStaticGlobalSetup()
    {
        doGlobalSetup();
        return 0;
    }
}
MyClass myInstance(doStaticGlobalSetup() + 1,2,3);

int main() {
   myInstance.doSomething();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely have to defer **any** constructor calls until after global initialization is done, and want to be sure that no static order initialization fiasco happens, there is a way: make `myInstance` a reference to uninitialized block of memory and create object in it using placement new after global initializaton.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct foo
{
    foo() { std::cout << "created\n"; }
    void meow() { std::cout << "used\n"; }
    ~foo() { std::cout << "destroyed\n"; }
};
void doGlobalSetup() { std::cout << "Global setup\n"; }


//Actual implementation
namespace {
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(foo), alignof(foo)>::type bar;
}
foo& instance = reinterpret_cast<foo&>(bar);

//Allows automatic creation and destruction
struct initializer
{
    initializer()
    {
        if (!initialized)
            new (&instance) foo();
        initialized = true;
    }
    ~initializer()
    {
        if(initialized)
            instance.~foo();
        initialized = false;
    }
    private:
        static bool initialized;
};
bool initializer::initialized = false;

int main()
{
    doGlobalSetup();
    initializer _;
    instance.meow();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it answers the question. Does it?

Comment: @YSC Why doesn't it: Placement new sounds like a great idea, especially if the object isn't copyable.

Comment: Ho I get it. It wasn't obvious at first how the placement new answered the question. It does.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. I would change just a little: make `create()` and `destroy()` the constructor and destructor of a proxy class, and create an instance of this class in the start of `main()`(and after calling `doGlobalSetup()`). That way I could still have automatic lifetime management for the instance.

Answer (score 3):

Use a static variable inside a function.

```
MyClass &myInstance() {
   doGlobalSetup();
   static MyClass myInstance(1,2,3);
   return myInstance;
}

void func() {
   myInstance().doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably already got the answer you wanted. But just to cover the whole spectrum: if, for some reason, you want to make sure that other places in the code don't accidentally construct MyClass independently of your global variable--and before the global setup has been made--you need to solve this with linking.

If you're on Linux, you can LD_PRELOAD a shared-object containing just the symbol for MyClass's constructor. In it, you declare the setup function accordingly, and let the dynamic linker do the job for you. Then, inside the constructor, you call the setup function, and then do a `dlsym("...", RTLD_NEXT)` to get the pointer to the original constructor, and you call it, passing it the arguments you got. Of course, you maintain and check a static flag for whether setup has already been performed.

Again, this is probably overkill for you, but I'm posting it just in case someone needs (and is able to use) this kind of solution.

P.S. This is what you get when you rely on global state! :)

Comment: Errr ... NO this is EXACTLY what I was looking for.  In my real-world puzzle, I happen not to have control over actually calling doGlobalSetup().   Imagine I am working in a framework where I have to write a C++ function that has a well known name.  In my C++ function, I have the global state class instance.  When I link my C++ function with the framework, the global class object is intantiated before the framework is ready and before my linked in user code function is given control.

Answer (score 0):

First, bear in mind that given a library init function like `doGlobalSetup` there is a distinct nonzero chance the library *will just not work* if you create a global instance.

Otherwise it's super easy to create an initializer with the comma operator:

```
bool do_my_setup = (doGlobalSetup(), true);
MyClass myInstance(1,2,3);
```